# ivy-immediate-done in doom emacs

Tags: doom

I want to use `ivy-immediate-done` in doom emacs, but I can't find the command with `SPC-:`. I have install counsel via `package-install`.

Does anyone know what the keybinding of this command is? I tried `C-m-j` with no success.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but just for clarification purpose: is it a typo that you tried `C-m-j` instead of `C-M-j`? :joy:

Comment: @TerryTsao This was it. I forgot about the meta-key, and just considered the notation 'C-M-j' I read online as meaning Ctrl-m-j, which in my mind was equivalent. So I could've written 'C-M-j' as well. Thank you very much for catching this, I can auto-complete without problems now, though I'm still not able to find 'ivy-immediate-done' by typing it in doom. But it works, so that's what matters.

Comment: I discovered why `ivy-immediate-done` is not in `counsel-M-x` when you type it. See my own [Q & A session](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/61717/30574). :-)

Comment: @TerryTsao Nice