# Why ivy-immediate-done is not shown in counsel-M-x

Tags: commands, ivy

I realize that `ivy-immediate-done` is not shown in `counsel-M-x`. Since it's an interactive command, I'm assuming `counsel-M-x` somehow filters it from its result. But a quick search of the function name in its code directory fails to find the relevant logic. I'm wondering what I am missing here. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! Don't know why I missed the first time.

Here's why: [Code](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/blob/6a22192f11a4aa0d43692bf685fd9b9d75911d00/ivy.el#L303-L307)

```lisp
(defun ivy-define-key (keymap key def)
  "Forward to (`define-key' KEYMAP KEY DEF).
Remove DEF from `counsel-M-x' list."
  (put def 'no-counsel-M-x t)
  (define-key keymap key def))
```