# Why is ivy-switch-buffer not found in counsel-M-x, but works when called by C-x b (or from the scratch buffer)

Tags: commands, ivy

According to helpful-key, C-x b is bound to ivy switch buffer:

[image]

According to the code, that is an interactive function. However, when I look for it in the Counsel-M-x menu, it's not found:

[image]

I figured since this is an interactive function, I should be able to call it from the M-x menu. I'm able to call it from the scratch buffer using eval-last-sexp, and through C-x b, but not M-x. Why wouldn't this show up in the M-x menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I figured since this is an interactive function, I should be able to call it from the M-x menu.

You can call it from `M-x` (`execute-extended-command`), just not from `M-x` (`counsel-M-x`).  IOW, you have probably enabled `counsel-mode` which remaps `M-x` to `counsel-M-x`.

Quoth Counsel's [Changelog file](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/blob/master/doc/Changelog.org#counsel-m-x-9):

> #### counsel-M-x
>
> Some commands are intended to be called only via their key binding. Make them disappear
> from `counsel-M-x` like this:
>
> ```el
> (put 'counsel-find-symbol 'no-counsel-M-x t)
> ```
>
> See [#2270](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/2270).

And indeed, by inspection, we see that:

```el
(function-get #'ivy-switch-buffer 'no-counsel-M-x) ; => t
```

So if you want `ivy-switch-buffer` (or any similar command) to show up as a candidate in `counsel-M-x` completion, you can say something like the following:

```el
(function-put #'ivy-switch-buffer 'no-counsel-M-x nil)
```

See also [Why ivy-immediate-done is not shown in counsel-M-x](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/61647/15748).